# is FBML compliant with HTML standards?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, fbml

this funny thing called FBML http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/ I'm just wondering is it true that any web page that uses FBML automatically disqualifies themselves as a 100% standard-compliant webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBML is a language developed by Facebook (which is [now deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)). Even their [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), which does not introduce custom tags, is technically not an open standard either, though it may be too early to say whether social networking sites could join up to make one. XMPP's Pubsub specification might be the closest equivalent to a standard here, but I don't think it is well-supported by many clients or services, even though Google made a derivative of it.

HTML5 has tended to just standardize on existing browser behavior, so anything that includes the HTML5`<!DOCTYPE html>` and works in all browsers without plugins might be considered compliant to an open standard. So JavaScript is an open standard, but they are not using an open standard as far as a social networking API. It's a bit of a relative term.

Comment: You have an interesting definition of "standard". FBML is an XHTML namespace, not a standard.

Comment: You're right--that didn't come out right. Amended. But technically speaking, it is is a language which is associated with a namespace, not a namespace. :)

Comment: @ceejayoz, I have to agree with brettz9.  A language is a set of strings ( http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/theory/lang_def.shtml#Language ), that often comes with some way of associating semantics with those strings.  By that definition, FBML defines a language.  For FBML, the set includes those XHTML strings that include a namespace declaration to a particular URL, and maybe some elements in that namespace.  The semantics are related to the transformation that the FBML processor performs to produce output XHTML.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's certainly no standard.

Comment: ok so if i want to make a 100% standard html5 page that uses fbml.. i'm out of luck ? (since its deprecated.. i'm not doing it, but just a sort of theoretical question)

Comment: @Mike: Maybe you didn't see that I corrected the text from before, when I had called FBML a standard (technically, one could use it as a standard, but it wasn't meant to be, so ceejayoz was right to correct me).

Comment: @Pacerier: As long as you use the DOCTYPE, I don't really know that you can make a non-standard HTML5 page. There may be recommendations within HTML5 not to use something, but HTML5 also defines how everything including "mistakes" should be handled. (a little how modern linguists don't prescribe "proper" language--they just accept all dialects as valid & expressive even if they note some are more socially acceptable; avoiding non-standard elements and attributes, except for the reserved data-* ones would probably be would be more socially acceptable but not doing so would not be forbidden).

Comment: If HTML ever evolves (as XHTML had been trying to do) to completely phase out some behavior, it may become practically important, but from what I see, the current WhatWG group is for now accepting the status quo completely.

Comment: @brettz9 i don't get it.. do you mean that as long as i put the `<!DOCTYPE html>` the behavior of `<fb:etc>` is "standardized" in the specifications and (thus.. in the future) across all browsers / platforms?

Comment: Especially since the (relative) demise of XHTML (which was moving toward the distinct namespaces of XML which would preserve validity so long as browsers supported a given namespace), no one seems to be making any promises about future compatibility, but yes, the aim of HTML5 is for backward compatibility (to a fault, imo), so it seems to stand to reason it should be that way going forward. The only thing I have heard of being possibly removed in the future (the one thing I think ought NOT to be removed) are HTML pseudo-comments <?...> (similar to XML processing instructions).

Comment: Basically, if it is a very rarely used feature you might not be safe, but using arbitrary "XML", especially with colons in the tag names (which are reserved in XML Namespaces and understood as being used for this role) I don't think could be that rare, nor do I think there would be future reason to require bound prefixes for other purposes--the community instead seems to dislike them), and since the browsers seem in support of XBL2 which supports arbitrary XML, I'd say that looks like a very, very safe bet.

Comment: (Even JavaScript you write today could technically be "unsafe" if the WhatWG continues to add new global objects, however much they use search engine archives to verify the rarity of these names.) But I wouldn't use your own markup with its own default namespace without a prefix since HTML just ignores namespaces (only XHTML does) and the tag names could conflict with future tags.

Comment: @brettz9 . btw what are the pseudo-comments you are talking about? i googled and found this link: http://simon.html5.org/test/html/parsing/pseudo-comments/demo/ is it the same thing which u r talking about?

Comment: @brettz9 o yea keep the @Pacerier in else only the person who posted this answer will b notified

Comment: @Pacerier: `<?...>` is treated as a comment in HTML, whereas in XML it is recognized as a different type; it has no use in HTML, so there's no reason to use it anyways, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @brettz9 interesting.. I'd always thought the only way to comment in HTML is `<!--` so is the `<?` comment a new thing or did it exist way back in the age of IE6 ?

Comment: It's existed a long time, not sure whether from what version of HTML. Anyways, it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

If the page is XHTML, it is valid XHTML if you include the proper `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"` namespace declaration in the `<html>` tag.

Comment: so what about a html page with the `<!DOCTYPE html> declaration` ?

Comment: That I'm not certain about. You could always try validating a simple test page.

Comment: i know it definitely does not validate OK http://html5.validator.nu/. However brettz9 (the comments in the other answer) also said **but HTML5 also defines how everything including "mistakes" should be handled** so now i'm abit confused